# Video Options Not Saving

Tags: origin, the-saboteur, ea-desktop

I'm trying to play The Saboteur through Origin/EA Desktop and I'm running into an issue that is forcing a 800x600 resolution with default settings despite editing the config files in multiple places.

I've edited:

-My Games\The Saboteur™\SaveGames\config.ini

-VideoSetup.exe in the main game directory

-SaboteurLauncher.exe in the main game directory

All have the same settings and resolution (1920x1080) but the game is still forcing its settings. My specs are more than capable to run the game well with the latest drivers. Is there a way I can get the game to force the settings I want to use?

### Specs

-Intel i7-7700k

-GTX 1080

-16 GB of DDR4 @ 3200 MHz

-1920x1080 144 Hz Monitor

-Windows 10 64-bit on Update 20H2

Comment: Please add what kind of video card you are using, monitor, operating system please.

Comment: @Sorean I added them, let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Does setting the config.ini file to read-only after applying changes help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot check the solution myself, but few other users seems to have encountered the same error a while ago on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/gog/comments/54a1k2/gog_the_saboteur/d80am80/) and on [GOG](https://www.gog.com/forum/the_saboteur/game_wont_let_me_play_at_1080p144hz_changes_resolution_to_800x600_when_i_choose_that). And PCGamingWiki lists it as [a known bug](https://www.pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/The_Saboteur#Game_only_runs_at_640x480_resolution) too. According to these sources, the problem is the game launching on 144Hz refresh rate which it doesn't seem to support, so it forces the 800x600 resolution when run in 144Hz. Since you have a monitor with a 144Hz refresh rate, this might be why it's forcing the 800x600 resolution on you. And according to them, you can play the game in 1920x1080 resolution if you have selected 60Hz as the refresh rate. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find any concrete solution on how to play in 144Hz refresh rate, **but evidently you can play on 1920x1080 resolution if you chose to run it in 60Hz refresh rate**.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help! I also found the [solution to the high refresh rate problem here](https://www.pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/The_Saboteur).

Comment: Fantastic. Cheers!